# Как перебрать два массива?

Tags: php

Как перебрать два массива методом foreach что бы получился такой результат:

Alex - DJ
Tim - Bass
Dave - Bass

```
$arr1 = [
1 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'DJ'],
2 => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bass'],
3 => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Vocal'],
];

$arr2 = [
    ['name' => 'Alex', 'specId' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Tim', 'specId' => 2],
    ['name' => 'Dave',  'specId' => 2],
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr2 as $item) {
    echo "{$item['name']}: {$arr1[$item['specId']]['name']}\n";
}
```